# Tips on improving/refactoring slow query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, performance, performance-tuning

Let's play lotto!

Ok. I have a `numbers` table with 80 rows (numbers 1-80):

```
create table dbo.numbers (knum tinyint primary key identity);
```

I have a table with the `drawid`, and each number drawn.

```
create table dbo.draws (drawid int, drawnumber tinyint);
```

Now, given that the `draws` table may have data like:

```
drawid   drawnumber
  1         10
  1         36
  1         54
  1         75
  2          9
  2         45
  2         46
  2         72
```

I want to find out when was the last time every possible three-number permutation occurred.

I'm using this:

```
declare @curdraw int
select @curdraw = max( drawid)-100 from draws;

select TOP 10 K1,K2,K3, @curdraw-max(d1.drawid)  from THREES 
inner join DrawNumbers d1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON K1 = D1.DRAWNUMBER
INNER JOIN DRAWNUMBERS D2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON K2 = D2.DRAWNUMBER AND D1.DRAWID = D2.DRAWID
INNER JOIN DRAWNUMBERS D3 WITH (NOLOCK) ON K3 = D3.DRAWNUMBER AND D1.DRAWID = D3.DRAWID
WHERE D1.DRAWID < @CURDRAW

GROUP  BY K1, K2, K3
ORDER BY @curdraw-max(d1.drawid) DESC
```

(Oh, and table `Threes` is a table with all 492,000+ three-number combinations from 1-80)

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do here? This particular query is just very slow and I'm sure someone with better math/grouping skills could do better.

---

Answers to comments - clarifications:

- It's for a keno game. Every draw has 20 numbers out of the 80. I just showed 4 each as an example.
- Two years of accumulated draws, at 254 draws a day with 20 numbers per draw... `Drawnumber` table is currently 3.7 mil rows. Also, what I'm looking for specifically is "out of every 3-number combination possible can you give me a sorted list of how long it has been since any one of them has hit, ordered by that length".
- The `top 10` is merely because I don't need to see all 490K results.

The primary keys:

```
USE [OKD] 
GO 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DrawNumbers] 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_DrawNumbers] 
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ( [DrawID] ASC, [DrawNumber] ASC )
  WITH 
   (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [OKD] 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[threes] 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ( [THREEID] ASC )
  WITH
    (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
     SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
     ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: What indices have you got? How slow is your *very slow* and how fast do you want it to be?

Comment: `"out of every 3-number combination possible"` -- 80 total numbers, combinations of 3, no repeats = 80 choose 3 = [82,160](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=80+choose+3). The result set should have that many rows, or fewer if combinations that haven't been hit don't show up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing it to use a CTE will be faster probably - they normally give the optimizer a better chance at optimising the query.

```
with currentdraw as (
select k1,k2,k3 from THREES 
inner join DrawNumbers d1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON K1 = D1.DRAWNUMBER
INNER JOIN DRAWNUMBERS D2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON K2 = D2.DRAWNUMBER AND D1.DRAWID = D2.DRAWID
INNER JOIN DRAWNUMBERS D3 WITH (NOLOCK) ON K3 = D3.DRAWNUMBER AND D1.DRAWID = D3.DRAWID
WHERE D1.DRAWID = @CURDRAW
), previousdraws as (
select d1.drawid, k1,k2,k3 from THREES 
inner join DrawNumbers d1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON K1 = D1.DRAWNUMBER
INNER JOIN DRAWNUMBERS D2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON K2 = D2.DRAWNUMBER AND D1.DRAWID = D2.DRAWID
INNER JOIN DRAWNUMBERS D3 WITH (NOLOCK) ON K3 = D3.DRAWNUMBER AND D1.DRAWID = D3.DRAWID
WHERE D1.DRAWID < @CURDRAW
)
select previousdraws.*
from previousdraws p
inner join currentdraw c
on p.k1 = c.k1 and p.k2 = c.k2 and p.k3 = c.k3
order by drawid desc
```

Your best indexes will probably be:

```
create index ix1 on THREES (k1,k2,k3);
create index ix1 on DrawNumbers (drawid, drawnumber);
```

Comment: `CTE will be faster probably - they normally give the optimizer a better chance at optimising the query` This is not completely true. See some excellent answers at (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14492/8783) and (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13117/8783) by @JNK

Comment: I'm setting this as the answer because the solution I came up with was a hybrid between an actual static table with the various combinations, and a CTE connecting this table with the results table. 

Plus, this was the only answer given. 

Well done, Dave! :)

Comment: As always, you should *measure* performance as performance depends not only on the query, but also the data, the business logic available (for optimisations) and other variables like stats, server performance and more. I can tell you that I have successfully used CTEs to *measurably* improve performance dozens of times.