# Get data per Customer and per Date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

How will I get the all the date even though there is no order between two dates?

Sample Table

```
OrderID  | Date      | CusID
33942    | 6-21-2014 | 6005
34059    | 6-20-2014 | 4003
53333    | 6-23-2014 | 6005
59234    | 6-23-2014 | 4003
```

How I could have this result?

```
CusID   | Date      | OrderID |
4003    | 6-20-2004 | 34059   | 
4003    | 6-21-2004 | null    | 
4003    | 6-22-2004 | null    | 
4003    | 6-23-2004 | 59234   | 
6005    | 6-20-2004 | null    | 
6005    | 6-21-2004 | 33942   | 
6005    | 6-22-2004 | null    | 
6005    | 6-23-2004 | 53333   |
```

This what I did so far.

I create a calendar table

```
CREATE TABLE #Calendar
(
    [CalendarDate] DATETIME
)

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(Year, -1, @EndDate)


WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #Calendar
             (
                   CalendarDate
             )
             SELECT
                   @StartDate

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
      END
```

Then here is my query but does not give me the needed result

```
Select t.CusID, c.CalendarDate, t.OrderID 
From #Calendar c 
left outer join
#temp t
ON
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.CalendarDate, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.Date, 112)
Where c.CalendarDate Between '6-20-2014' and '6-23-2014'
Order By t.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need a table with customers. The customers table needs to be `CROSS JOIN`ed with the calendar table to get the list of all possible dates per customer.

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/792fe/2) demonstrates the query that gets the desired result. Please note that your database schema may have a table with customers, and you may not need a `customers` CTE I have created. Just use your existing customers table to CROSS JOIN it with the calendar table.

Also, as you use SQL Server 2008, it is about time you've learned CTE. It is much easier to use them than the temp tables. However, do not overuse them. Do not use them when performance is very important. Please read this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/whats-the-difference-between-a-cte-and-a-temp-table) to better understand when to use CTE vs Temp tables

Another note: when truncating times from the datetime columns do not use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.CalendarDate, 112)`. It is about the slowest possible method. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server) for more info

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([OrderID] int, [Date] DATETIME, [CusID] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([OrderID], [Date], [CusID])
VALUES
    (33942, '6-21-2014', 6005),
    (34059, '6-20-2014', 4003),
    (53333, '6-23-2014', 6005),
    (59234, '6-23-2014', 4003)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(Year, -1, @EndDate)

;with calendar as (
  SELECT CAST(@StartDate AS DATE) CalendarDate
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, CalendarDate) FROM calendar
  WHERE CalendarDate < @EndDate
  ),
customers as (
  SELECT DISTINCT CusID FROM Table1
  )
SELECT a.CusID, c.CalendarDate, OrderID
FROM customers a CROSS JOIN Calendar c 
LEFT JOIN Table1 t
ON CAST(c.CalendarDate AS DATE) = CAST(t.[Date] AS DATE) AND a.CusID = t.CusID
WHERE CAST(c.CalendarDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '6-20-2014' and '6-23-2014'
ORDER BY 1, 2
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/792fe/2/0)**:

```
| CUSID | CALENDARDATE | ORDERID |
|-------|--------------|---------|
|  4003 |   2014-06-20 |   34059 |
|  4003 |   2014-06-21 |  (null) |
|  4003 |   2014-06-22 |  (null) |
|  4003 |   2014-06-23 |   59234 |
|  6005 |   2014-06-20 |  (null) |
|  6005 |   2014-06-21 |   33942 |
|  6005 |   2014-06-22 |  (null) |
|  6005 |   2014-06-23 |   53333 |
```

Comment: I, too am a fan of CTEs.  I agree they can greatly clarify the layout of code.  They have different performance characteristics to temporary tables, however, and each should be used where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have updated the answer to warn the OP about the difference between CTE and Temp tables with a link to a question that discusses the usage of each of them

Comment: While better than a loop, a recursive CTE is not much faster. Why not have a permanent calendar table? http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1 http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2 http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3 <-- pay particular attention to the perf results of the recursive CTEs in parts 1 & 2