# How to use an alias name that has RANK() OVER in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, window-functions

I have a query that has a `RANK() OVER` function inside it but I would like to use the results displayed on this column in the WHERE clause that follows. How do I write that as all the other questions I have looked at did not have `RANK() OVER` and seemed easier to do. Here is the statement:

```
USE SMSResults


SELECT Student_No,Result,Module_Name,Semester,Year,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Student_No ORDER BY Semester  DESC) AS Rnk
FROM tbl_results
WHERE Student_No = '201409'

ORDER BY Year DESC
```

I would like to use the `Rnk` column in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I would like to use the Rnk column in the WHERE clause

The `Rnk` is a column computed in the `SELECT` clause. It's not avaiable in the `WHERE` clause of the same level, as the logical order of execution a query is `FROM -> WHERE -> SELECT`.

You have to wrap the query in a subquery. You can use either a [CTE (Common Table Expression)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/):

```
USE SMSResults ;
go
with CTE as 
    ( SELECT Student_No,Result,Module_Name,Semester,Year,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Student_No ORDER BY Semester  DESC) AS Rnk
      FROM tbl_results
      WHERE Student_No = '201409')
select * from CTE 
where rnk > 1   -- change here with whatever you want ... !!
ORDER BY Year DESC ;
```

or a derived table:

```
USE SMSResults ;
go   
select * from
    ( SELECT Student_No,Result,Module_Name,Semester,Year,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Student_No ORDER BY Semester  DESC) AS Rnk
      FROM tbl_results
      WHERE Student_No = '201409') 
  AS derived_table
where rnk > 1   -- change here with whatever you want ... !!
ORDER BY Year DESC ;
```

As a side note for future readers - worth reading - [What's the difference between a CTE and a Temp Table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13117/8783) by [JNK♦](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1945/jnk)